# Very strange behavior of Django template loader

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm facing a very strange issue with my django project. I get this error:

[image: Error: Template does not exists]

As you can see it is obvious there is an error related to the absence of a template, right?

Well, here comes the blow:

[image]

So, Django itself said the file exists, whaaat!?

Have any of you struggled with this error before? What can be the problem here?

Comment: It is much more readable to post text as *text* instead of a hard to read screenshot